# replace all occurrences of a string

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to add a class to all `p` tags that contain arabic text in it. For example:

```
<p>لمبارة وذ</p> 
<p>do nothing</p> 
<p>خمس دقائق يخ</p> 
<p>مراعاة إبقاء 3 لاعبين</p>
```

should become

```
<p class="foo">لمبارة وذ</p> 
<p>do nothing</p>
<p class="foo">خمس دقائق يخ</p> 
<p class="foo">مراعاة إبقاء 3 لاعبين</p>
```

I am trying to use PHP `preg_replace` function to match the pattern (arabic) with following expression:

```
preg_replace("~(\p{Arabic})~u", "<p class=\"foo\">$1", $string, 1);
```

However it is not working properly. It has **two problems**:

1. It only matches the first paragraph.
2. Adds an empty `<p>`.

Sandbox [Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c7d5753c9d0b718b1604f4c7df333f452f45301)

Comment: What if it is not arabic?

Comment: @SimonKirsten then it should let it be as it is. I edited the example in the question, please see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It only matches the first paragraph.

This is because you added the last argument, indicating you want only to replace the first occurrence. Leave that argument out.

> Adds an empty `<p>`.

This is in fact the original `<p>` which you did not match. Just add it to the matching pattern, but keep it outside of the matching group, so it will be left out when you replace with `$1`.

Here is a corrected version, also on [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/747ba3b5676602ba4d0aea787d7d0fb1457b3ffd):

```
$text = preg_replace("~<p>(\p{Arabic}+)~u", "<p class=\"foo\">$1", $string);
```

Comment: Thanks but I see exactly same problems on the sandbox link you posted. Are you sure its correct link?

Comment: wrong link: this is it: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/747ba3b5676602ba4d0aea787d7d0fb1457b3ffd

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you weren't telling it to match the `<p>`, so it didn't.

Your main problem is that spaces aren't Arabic. Simply adding the alternative to match them fixes your problem:

```
$text = preg_replace("~<p>(\p{Arabic}*|\s*)~u", "<p class=\"foo\">$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using DOMDocument and DOMXPath:

```
$html = <<<'EOD'
<p>لمبارة وذ</p> 
<p>خمس دقائق يخ</p> 
<p>مراعاة إبقاء 3 لاعبين</p>
EOD;

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML('<div>'.$html.'</div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// here you register the php namespace and the preg_match function
// to be able to use it in the XPath query
$xpath->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$xpath->registerPhpFunctions('preg_match');

// select only p nodes with at least one arabic letter
$pNodes = $xpath->query("//p[php:functionString('preg_match', '~\p{Arabic}~u', .) > 0]");

foreach ($pNodes as $pNode) {
    $pNode->setAttribute('class', 'foo');
}

$result = '';
foreach ($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```